# How to upload splitted apk in to play store?

Tags: android, publishing, google-play-developer-api

I want to publish my app in spited Builds in to play store ,I have 4 Builds with different version code.
When I am uploading second build it is showing **error**.

> Version 400 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that might receive version 400 would receive version 500.

Answer (score 0):

Each APK must have a different set of target devices. These are specified with the following [Google Play filters](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SupportedFilters)